# Magento 2 : get customer attributes in sales_order_place_after event

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I have created an extension attribute called "sms_subscribed" using data patch.

I am trying to get it in observer.
is their any way to get it ?

OrderPlaceAfter.php

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class OrderPlaceAfter implements ObserverInterface

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
      $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    }
```

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
 protected $customerFactory;
 protected $customerRepository;

  public function __construct(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
            \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
        ) {
            $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
            $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        }
    
        public function execute(Observer $observer)
        {
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
            $customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->load($customerId);
            $customerAttribute = $customer->getSmsSubscribed();

            //or

            $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
            $customerAttribute = $customer->getCustomAttribute('sms_subscribed');          
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

How did You created extension Attribute exactly?
Are You sure You created Extension Attributes? For Extension Attributes You need to create extension_attributes.xml file in etc folder (and define there Extension attributes).

If You created DataPatch, I think You created just normal order attribute.
In that case You should be able to get it with

```
$order->getSmsSubscriber()
```

or

```
$order->getData('sms_subscribed')
```

But obviously this attribute can not be empty.

Btw for extension attribute, You can use

```
$extensionAttribute = $order->getExtensionAttributes()
$extensionAttribute->getSmsSubscriber()
```

But obviously this extension attribute have to be set.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;

class OrderPlaceAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $customerRepository;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
    ) {
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($order->getCustomerId());
        $customerAttribute = $customer->getCustomAttribute('sms_subscribed');
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you!